# [Pandas]: Combining rows of Dataframe based on same column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the one below -

[image]

How can I combine the rows such that all the neighbourhoods belonging to the same Postcode are displayed in the same row seperated by commas. Something like this -

| Postcode | Borough | Neighbourhood |

| M1B | Scarborough | Rouge, Malvern |

| M5A | Downtown Toronto | Harbourfront, Regent Park |

| M6A | North York | Lawrence Heights, Lawrence Manor |

and the rest of the rows as they are...